# Compile Java file with external files inside. (chm)

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, chm

I am making a 1 file program in java, and I have a `.chm` file that I want to be called when the user asks how to use the program. I don't want to have the file outside the `.jar` file.

Maybe what I'm asking is impossible, the only thing I know about compiling is that if I hit "clean and build" button it generates a `.jar` file out of my `.java` files. Is there a way to do this?

PS: I use NetBeans to create java programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include any file inside a jar (it is a zip file). Then you have to use [`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get an access to the embedded file in your jar. That would return an [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) that you can use to get an `InputStream` by calling [`openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) and read from it, possibly extracting it to the hard drive for display, etc.

The use is to put such files in a "resource" or "res" folder, inside the "src" directory. Here is how it looks in my Eclipse:

[image: Test project with resources]

Then I access my images by:

```
URL uImg = getClass().getResource("/res/16/Actions-edit-delete-icon-16.png");
InputStream is = uImg.openStream();
// Read the content from 'is' e.g. to extract it somewhere
is.close();
```

EDIT: As an example, to extract your file `"TJ.chm"` from `"res"` directory of your jar into a file `"/tmp/TJ.chm"` you would do like:

```
// Add all necessary try/catch
InputStream is = ucmh.openStream();
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/TJ.chm"));
int len = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Or whichever size you prefer
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > -1)
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
os.close();
is.close();
```

Comment: hm... can you use pictures please? :P

Comment: @user3212168 sorry I use Eclipse. I'll try to add what I have though :)

Comment: @user3212168 I edited my answer and added an image of how it looks like on Eclipse. Note that it should be the same on NetBeans, as you have to add the resource directory under your "src" source directory.

Comment: how would the code look like if I was trying to open a file called TJ.chm on the res folder?

Comment: @user3212168 I added a complete example of how to extract the file on the hard drive. Tell me if it's enough for you.